# How do I limit UITextField length AND character types at the same time?

Tags: swift2, uitextfield, limit

I have an iOS Xcode 7.3 project I working on using `Swift2`. I've looked all over and found ways to limit the length of text in a `UITextField`.  I've also seen ways to limit the types of characters that an be typed in a `UITextField`.

I've used in my project for length `limit`:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    let limitLength = 3
    return newLength <= limitLength
}
```

I've used this for limiting the text to only numeric values:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let numberOnly = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersInString: "0123456789")
    let stringFromTextField = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersInString: string)
    let strValid = numberOnly.isSupersetOfSet(stringFromTextField)

    return strValid
}
```

Both work great once I set my `UITextField` to the `UITextFieldDelegate`.  However, I need my project to do both.  How do I do that?  How can I combine the two since they each have a different `return` type and value?

The issue is when I use the iPad, it allows for other characters besides numeric because the `.NumberPad` for the iPad allows for characters such as `&,$,%`, etc.  The iPhone has no issues, but my project is a universal app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply only return from the first type of check if the condition is `false`, otherwise continue to the second check:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    let limitLength = 3
    if newLength > limitLength {
        return false
    }

    let numberOnly = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersInString: "0123456789")
    let stringFromTextField = NSCharacterSet.init(charactersInString: string)
    let strValid = numberOnly.isSupersetOfSet(stringFromTextField)

    return strValid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom numeric field class to make it easier to use it across your projects. Just override the method awakeFromNib (it gets called once it has been loaded), add a target to your field for control event .EditingChanged to monitor the user input and set your keyboard type there. You will need also to add a computed property to your field to filter the unwanted characters:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class NumericField: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int = 3
    @IBInspectable var allowedCharacters: String = "0123456789"
    var filteredText: String {
        return String((text ?? "")
            .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: allowedCharacters)
            .invertedSet)
            .joinWithSeparator("")
            .characters.prefix(maxLength))
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        keyboardType = .NumberPad
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
        editingChanged(self)
    }
    func editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        sender.text = String(Int(filteredText) ?? 0)
    }
}
```